# AttributeError: type object 'Wav2Vec2ForCTC' has no attribute 'from_pretrained'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to fine tune Wav2Vec2 model for medical vocabulary. When I try to run the following code on my VS Code Jupyter notebook, I am getting an error, but when I run the same thing on Google Colab, it works fine.

```
from transformers import Wav2Vec2ForCTC
 
model = Wav2Vec2ForCTC.from_pretrained(
    "facebook/wav2vec2-base", 
    gradient_checkpointing=True, 
    ctc_loss_reduction="mean", 
    pad_token_id=processor.tokenizer.pad_token_id,
)
```

And here is the error that I getting on my VS Code

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-926a81051d7b> in <module>
      1 from transformers import Wav2Vec2ForCTC
      2 
----> 3 model = Wav2Vec2ForCTC.from_pretrained(
      4     "facebook/wav2vec2-base",
      5     gradient_checkpointing=True,

AttributeError: type object 'Wav2Vec2ForCTC' has no attribute 'from_pretrained'
```

Comment: Check the version in both environments with `import transformers print(transformers.__version__)` and look for other packages with incompatible versions.

Comment: In VS Code the version is 4.4.0 and on Google Colab the version is 4.6.1. When I tried upgrading the version on my local copy, then it should me and error
```ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
datasets 1.4.1 requires huggingface-hub==0.0.2, but you have huggingface-hub 0.0.8 which is incompatible.```

Comment: Then downgrade to 0.0.2 or check the docs for which versions match.

Comment: Solved, I uninstalled both libraries and then installed again their required versions, thank you for helping me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved when I uninstalled both the libraries and installed their respective versions needed using following command:

```
pip uninstall huggingface-hub
pip uninstall transformers
pip install huggingface-hub==0.0.8
pip install transformers==4.6.1
```

After this the issue got resolved.